# Maximizing a subset of the binary vector space such that no sum of four distinct elements is zero

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I have researched a problem for about 2 years, and I want to know if there exists any previous results (I can't seem to find any). The problem goes:

What is the largest subset of a $2k$-dimensional vector space over the binary field $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that no four distinct elements in the subset sum to zero?

I have made an upper bound, and I want to know if there exists any at the moment.

Comment: What is a "binary field"? Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$, i.e. the Galois field of order $2^m$?

Comment: No, the case where m=1. So only with the elements 0 and 1

Comment: then it is not a field what you mean. Do you mean a vectorspace over $\mathbb{F}_2$ ?

Comment: Really? I suppose so, then. I mean the vectors with an even number of entries and where the only possibilities are 0 and 1

Comment: Absolutely - maybe in 50+-year old texts one might still call this object a "field", it is time to drop this.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will make sure to remember this

Comment: a field is an algebraic system with two operations, addition and multiplication, and in a vector space one cannot multiply vectors, generally speaking. There are of course "vector fields", too, but this is a complete different and irrelevant here thing.

Comment: If we have $m$ vectors, their $m(m-1)/2$ mutual sums must all be different, thus $m(m-1)\leqslant 2^{2k+1}$. Is your upper bound much better? As for the lower bound, a greedy algorithm gives something like $C\cdot 2^{2k/3}$ vectors.

Comment: Ah, we may get $2^k-1$ vectors: look at our space as a plane over $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ and consider all vectors $(x,1/x)$. The key word to search is Sidon set.

Comment: My bound is a bit better than the first one you mentioned. However, I do not see how the sum of two vectors cannot equal the sum of some other two vectors. And how is this directly linked to the problem of finding four distinct elements that do not add to zero?

Comment: As for the Sidon sets, do this not only apply in the instances where we want to look at pairwise distinct sums? And not necessarily for a sum of 4 vectors?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: as to the lower bound, a subset $S \subset\mathbb{F}_2^{2k}$ of cardinality $m$, with the property "no 4 distinct vectors of its sum to zero" is maximal wrto this property iff $S+S+S=\mathbb{F}_2^{2k}$, whence $m+{m\choose 3}\ge 2^{2k}$ (so $C=6+o(1)$).

Comment: (cubic root of $6$ )

Comment: @JoakimFærgeman $a+b+c+d=0$ iff $a+b=c+d$, right?

Comment: @PietroMajer yes, but in another comment I show that this greedy estimate may be improved significantly by an explicit construction

Comment: I see. I understand that if for non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ one has $(a,1/a)+ (b,1/b)+(c,1/c)+(d,1/d)=0$ then $(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)(X-d)=X^4+pX^2+q$. Can we conclude that the polynomial on the RHS has a double root (even in car=2) ?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov ah yes, that is correct. Actually I have only recently found out that I could state my problem in this way, so I have worked very little with sums. The bound you mention is actually uite trivial, yes, and my bound is better (although not significantly). I still do not understand how you derive your second bound of 2^k-1. In my understanding, this seems just incorrect?

Comment: @PietroMajer yes, it is $(X^2-U^2)(X^2-V^2)=(X-U)^2(X-V)^2$, where $U^2,V^2$ are roots of $X^2+pX+q$. Alternatively, you rewrite your equation in the form $(a,1/a)+(b,1/b)=(c,1/c)+(d,1/d)$, thus $a+b=c+d$ and $ab=cd$, so $(x-a)(x-b)=(x-c)(x-d)$.